# How can I get the pid of a process started this way

Tags: shell-script, process

```
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo /var/run/out
while true
do
    cat /var/run/out | nc -l 8080 > >(
        while read line
        do
            do some stuff
        done
    )
done
```

How can I get the pid of `nc` and `cat`? Using $! doesn't work. I want to write them to a pid file.

Comment: Did you try to get it from ps command? I am not sure if it will work but may work.

Comment: I'd like to get the pid within the script to write it to a pid file.

Answer (score 4):

There may be a more elegant way of doing what you want, but this works:

```
do
    (cat /var/run/out& echo $! > cat_pid; wait) |
                            (nc -l 8080 <&0 & echo $! > nc_pid; wait) > >(
                ︙
```

(broken into separate lines after the `|` for readability). 
This works by wrapping each command whose PID you want in a subshell,
running it asynchronously in that subshell, capturing its PID,
and then waiting for the command to finish. 
(This, in effect, puts the command back into the foreground.) 
Use [Scott’s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146465/80216) `<&0` trick
to get an asynchronous process in a script to read its rightful standard input.

<strike>But [why are you using “cat”](https://superuser.com/q/323060/354511)?
And [why are you using `> >(…)` instead of simple piping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146263/80216)?</strike>

You could simplify this a little as:

```
while true
do
    (nc -l 8080 < /var/run/out & echo $! > nc_pid; wait) |
                while read line
                do
                    do some stuff
                done
done
```

letting `nc` read directly from `/var/run/out`,
and using a simple pipe instead of process substitution.

Comment: The code was taken from another answer on stack overflow. Your idea with pipes sounds better, can you show me how you would write it out?

Comment: This seems like a much better way. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I have to unaccept because the script no longer behaves in the same way. If I start it up using your code, then access the machine through a browser on port 8080, it never gets to the 'do some stuff' part.

Comment: Are you talking about my first answer or my revised answer? Does the "do some stuff" write to `/var/run/out`? It occurred to my last night that might cause deadlock that might be an issue, and might be why the original author(s) chose the `cat … |`. Try going back to my first answer; if that works, then maybe try changing the `> >(…)` to `| …`.

Comment: The revised answer results in a deadlock, yes. I'll test out the first part some more and accept if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way I can think of is to get the pid before you launch the process.

For example (in bash):

```
pidfile() { (
    echo $BASHPID > "$1"
    shift
    exec "$@"
) }

mkfifo /var/run/out
while true
do
    pidfile /tmp/cat.pid cat /var/run/out | pidfile /tmp/nc.pid nc -l 8080 > >(
        while read line
        do
            do some stuff
        done
    )
done
```

This creates a `pidfile` function that writes the current PID to the specified file, and then executes the rest of the arguments using `exec`. The `exec` causes the command to be run with the same pid as the shell that just wrote out the file.

We wrap the entire `pidfile()` function inside parenthesis `()` so that we can ensure it executes in a subshell. The situation where this becomes critical is when you execute a command that isn't in a pipeline. For example:

```
pidfile /tmp/foo some command here
```

When you do it this way, `pidfile()` is going to run in the same process as the rest of the script, and so when it calls `exec`, the command being run will take over the PID, and the script will no longer be running.

Also note, that the above is all written for bash. `$BASHPID` is a bash specific variable. `$$` does not change when using a subshell, so the value is incorrect for our use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the PID of `cat` or `nc` *in that script* unless you [background the processes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_do_I_run_a_job_in_the_background.3F) with `&`. Any process you don't background is going to have to *finish* before the script continues.

The [Bash wiki process management article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) explains how to do such things sanely.