# Get PID of any command in backgrounded piped sequence of commands

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, job-control

If, in `bash`, I execute:

```
cmd1 | cmd2 | ... | cmdi | ... | cmdn &
```

where the `cmd{1..n}` may not be distinct, how do I get the PID of `cmdi`? Alternatively, how can I signal the `cmdi` process? (For example, send it `SIGUSR1`?)
`pkill`/`pgrep`, `pidof` etc. don't look like good answers, since other instances of `cmdi` maybe running, including as part of the same pipeline. `jobs -p` gives the PID of `cmd1`, for me.

`i` can be anything in `{1..n}`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the pid of a process started this way](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150739/how-can-i-get-the-pid-of-a-process-started-this-way)

Comment: @G-Man Care to explain? I see only superficial similarity, and as I explained in Ramesh's answer, modifying the set of commands is of not much use.

Comment: Superficial similarity? `cat /var/run/out | nc -l 8080` is only *superficially similar* to `cmd1 | cmd2`? Your constraint, that you want to type the bare-bones pipeline ***and then*** recover the PIDs, is (1) not stated in the question, and (2) unlikely to allow for a good, general solution.

Comment: @G-Man On the contrary, you are imposing constraints that simple aren't stated. `cmd1 | cmd2` is a very special case where both PIDs are easily obtainable. Did I say anything about n? So why would you assume n=2? Did I say anything about what cmdi is? So why would you assume I could modify cmdi? I am asking for a general solution and you are imposing restrictions.

Answer (score 7):

For the original version of the question, when only the last command's PID was desired, the special variable `$!` is perfect.

```
foo | bar | baz &
baz_pid=$!
```

There's no similar easy access to the PIDs of the other processes.

It took a long time for `$pipestatus` (zsh) and `$PIPESTATUS` (bash) to be added, finally giving us access to all of the exit statuses in a pipeline, in addition to the `$?` for the last one that has been around since the original Bourne shell. Maybe something analogous will happen with `$!` eventually.

Comment: Would you mind if I edited the question to ask for the PID of an arbitrary command in the list as well? Or should I start a new question?

Comment: You'll probably have to wait a lot longer for an answer to that one. I don't have strong feelings about stackexchange site organization so separate question, edit question, whatever... won't bother me

Comment: That's okay, the immediate problem is solved, now curiosity is in charge. I'll edit it then. Just a heads-up, since I have seen questions change drastically and leaving the older answers looking very out-of-place.

Comment: @muru - note it would've been better to make it a new Q referencing this one.

Comment: @slm duly noted. Will do so in future.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could do something as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786955/1742825).

```
(ls -l | echo "Hello" | df -h & echo $! >&3 ) 3>pid
```

Here in the above example, I have retrieved the pid of third piped process and noted it down to the file pid. I could note it down for any piped process.

Comment: Interesting, but this would involve modifying the set of commands. Not much use once the commands have been executed.

Comment: @muru - what? what use is any PID once it has finished execution? do you want the pipeline's PID? `jobs -p`. signal it with `SIGPIPE`. Do you want `cmdi` - this.

Comment: @mikeserv Not if they are in the background, running as we speak. By what sorcery am I supposed to modify the command line for that?

Comment: @muru that would be a sorcery. you need a debugger.

Comment: I find this to be a useful pattern for starting background processes, waiting for them to reach some state, and then killing them.  In case anybody is interested: https://gist.github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/d25aafb4131a8a14ca2a6d05a3dd88e9

Answer (score 2):

A not-very-portable, Linux-specific solution could be to track the processes using the pipes that connect them. We can get the PIDs of the first (`jobs -p`) and last (`$!`) commands in the pipeline. Using either PID, this script could do the job:

```
#! /bin/bash

PROC=$1
echo $PROC

if [[ $(readlink /proc/$PROC/fd/1) =~ ^pipe: ]]
then
    # Assuming first process in chain...
    NEXT_FD=1
elif [[ $(readlink /proc/$PROC/fd/0) =~ ^pipe: ]]
then
    # Last process in chain...
    NEXT_FD=0
else
    # Doesn't look like a pipe.
    exit
fi

NEXT_PROC_PIPE=$(readlink /proc/$PROC/fd/$NEXT_FD)

while [[ $NEXT_PROC_PIPE =~ ^pipe: ]] 
do
    PROC=$(find /proc/*/fd -type l -printf "%p/%l\n" 2>/dev/null | awk -F'/' '($6 == "'"$NEXT_PROC_PIPE"'") && ($3 != "'$PROC'" ) {print $3}')
    NEXT_PROC_PIPE=$(readlink /proc/$PROC/fd/$NEXT_FD)
    echo $PROC
done
```

Comment: For the curious, there's more about this kind of thing here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486233/146169

Answer (score 0):

I use zero-based arrays here in this code. Just be careful what you run by `eval`.

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd=('sleep 10' 'sleep 2' 'sleep 5')
first=1
for c in "${cmd[@]}"; do
  ((first)) && { pipe=$c; first=0; } || pipe+='|'$c
done
shopt -u lastpipe
eval $pipe &

printf 'Pipe:\n%s\n\n' "$pipe"

shellpid=$BASHPID
parent=$(ps -o pid= --ppid $shellpid | head -n -1)
declare -a pids=()
mapfile -t pids < <(printf '%s\n' $(ps -o pid= --ppid $parent))
printf '%s\n' 'Listing the arrays:'
printf '%2s %6s %s\n' i PID command
for i in "${!cmd[@]}"; do
    printf '%2d %6d %s\n' "$i" "${pids[i]}" "${cmd[i]}"
done

printf '\n%s\n' 'ps listing:'
ps xao pid,ppid,command | head -n 1
ps xao pid,ppid,command | tail | head -n -3
```