# Determine if process is "connected" to another process via pipes

Tags: pipe, node.js

If I do this:

```
x | y
```

is there any way to check, during the runtime of x, to see if it's connected to y?  Note that I don't know what y is, and I am not responsible for starting y.

Specifically, I am talking about the Node.js runtime, so perhaps this is a Node.js specific question. But ultimately, I am wondering if it's possible to determine given any runtime. Is it possible and how?

Is it possible to determine if the stdout/stderr are hooked up to the stdin of another process? I guess that's what this question is about.

Comment: If this were Linux, `/proc/<pid-x>/fd/1` and `/proc/<pid-y>/fd/0` would be links to the same pipe.

Comment: Yeah it has to work on MacOS too, so that exact technique won't work. Also note that I don't know what y is, I am not responsible for starting y. If I were, then I would already have the answer to this yes/no question :)

Comment: You don't need to know what Y is to inspect `/proc/*/fd/0` (on Linux, again). For example, I used `find` and `awk` for that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156152/70524

Comment: `lsof` should show processes that have the file opened as well

Comment: @muru ah, I see what you are saying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check whether the program's output is going to a pipe, based on https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats, you want to call `fs.fstat(FileDescriptor)` and then call `isFIFO()` on the returned `stat` object (FIFO == first-in-first-out == a pipe or a named pipe):

```
$ </dev/null node -e 'var fs=require("fs");
   fs.fstat(0,function(err,stats){ if(err) throw(err); console.log(stats.isFIFO()); });  ' 
  false
$  : | node -e 'var fs=require("fs");
   fs.fstat(0,function(err,stats){ if(err) throw(err); console.log(stats.isFIFO()); });  ' 
  true
```

In C, you'd make the `fstat` syscall and then test the `.st_mode` field of the returned `struct stat` using the `S_ISFIFO` macro.

If you like to waste CPU cycles and want to use an external binary, you can execute `test -p /dev/fd/$THE_FD` to get the answer (or invoke that in a shell where `test` will be a builtin, or run `stat`, or launch something else capable of determining the file type).

Comment: will this really work? I haven't tried it yet

Comment: I guess you use 0 which is stdin right, but only stdin for process `y` is active?

Comment: @AlexanderMills In x (the potential left-hand side of a pipe), you'd run it with 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Ah that's good to know, I have always wondered how 0, 1 or 2 can mean anything, but perhaps process id is paired with the fd information by fstat?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Of course. Fds have no system-global meaning. The kernel will always use the context of the current process when resolving a fd.

Comment: Thanks yeah my code has to work on MacOS too, so I wonder how fstat works, it must combine pid with fd, but on MacOS, `/proc/pid/fd/x` does not exist so dunno

Comment: thanks this seems to work...can you explain why stdin/stdout becomes a FIFO if it's connected in a pipe, and is not a FIFO if not connected in a pipe?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Thanks for accepting. I've added a note in parentheses (to repeat it: FIFO == first-in-first-out == a pipe or a named pipe).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, and fairly trivial, for a program to determine whether any given open file descriptor in its process references a pipe or a FIFO.  It is a simple exercise in the use of the `fstat()` library function.

You'll have to work out how to call `fstat()` in your programming language of choice.  In the C or C++ languages a function to do this is quite simple:

```
#include <sys/types.h>  // no longer required by IEEE 1003.1:2008
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/// \brief Check a file descriptor for being open and denoting a pipe/FIFO
extern inline
bool        /// \returns true if and only if the descriptor is open to a pipe/FIFO
is_fifo (
    int fd  ///< the file descriptor to test
) {
    struct stat s;
    return 0 <= fstat(fd, &s) && S_ISFIFO(s.st_mode);
}
```

The libsystemd library in systemd has a somewhat more complicated `sd_is_fifo()` library function.

Answer (score 1):

[Testing whether a file descriptor is a pipe is easy and portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383132). Figuring out what's at the other end of the pipe isn't.

Externally, with recent versions of `lsof` on `Linux`:

```
$ sleep 100 | sleep 200 &
[1] 15314 15315
$ lsof -ad0-1 -E -p 15314
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
sleep   15314 stephane    0u   CHR  136,1      0t0        4 /dev/pts/1
sleep   15314 stephane    1w  FIFO   0,10      0t0 17895049 pipe 15315,sleep,0r
```

Shows that stdout of 15314 is the writing end of a pipe which has the stdin of 15315 at the other  end.

Answer (score 0):

Using Node.js, in the runtime on a *nix system, this seems to work:

```
const isTTY = process.stdout.isTTY;
```

if true, it's not connected to a destination pipe

if undefined, it's connected to a destination pipe

...at least according to my testing so far

Comment: Stdout isn't limited to being either a terminal or a pipe. It can also be a regular file (if you're running under a redirection) (or I guess also a socket, character device or a block device, though I haven't tested with the last three types).

Comment: yeah my current understanding is this is not as reliable a measure as using `fstat`, I guess for the reasons you just mentioned