# How to determine if a process is part of a pipeline (producer in pipeline)?

Tags: pipe, tty, stdio

So if I am in my terminal and run:

```
$ my_proc | grep foo
```

in my_prof I know it's part of a pipeline because stdout is not attached to the terminal but to grep. On the other hand, if I just run this:

```
$ my_proc
```

in the terminal, then stdout is attached to the TTY, so I know that it's not part of a pipeline.

However, if I run my_proc programmatically outside of the context of a terminal, how can I know if it's part of a pipeline or not?

Or perhaps a better way to phrase the question, is there a way to discover what device/process is listening to the stdio from my_proc?

Comment: What platform are you using? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Also, can you be more precise about what you want? What does it mean to run it "programmatically"? Do you want to know **if** it's part of a pipeline, or discover the process at the other end? [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382849/determine-if-process-is-connected-to-another-process-via-pipes) is related, and may answer your first question, but perhaps not the second.