# Pid of process in loop launched by script

Tags: bash, process, kill

I have a number of processes launched via a bash script, listening for and playing, via netcat, audio streams arriving on separate ports:

```
#!/bin/bash
# listener.sh

while :
do
    nc -l 900$1 | aplay - 
    sleep 1
done

exit 0
```

This script is launched in another script with arguments to define unique ports. eg.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # startlisterners.sh

    if [ ! -f /tmp/listener1.pid ]; then
         nohup  listener.sh 1 &
        echo $! > /tmp/listener1.pid
    fi
    if [ ! -f /tmp/listener2.pid ]; then
         nohup  listener.sh 2 &
         echo $! > /tmp/listener2.pid
    fi

    ..... etc.

    exit 0
```

I need, periodically, to be able to selectively kill off instances of "aplay" in the subscripts while keeping the subscripts themselves running.

How can I access the individual PIDs of each aplay process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
nc -l 900$1 | aplay - 
sleep 1
```

run

```
nc -l "900$1" | aplay - &
   # here you can use $!
wait
sleep 1
```

Now where it reads `# here you can use $!` you can e.g. write `$!` to a predefined file. This approach may require `listener.sh` to know its number (`listener1`, `listener2` etc.) so it can use a file with the right number.

---

Another way is to define a trap before `while` in `listener.sh`:

```
trap 'kill "$!"' SIGUSR2
```

With this implemented, if you send `SIGUSR2` (`kill -s SIGUSR2 …`) to a `listener.sh` process then it will `kill` its own `aplay`. You already know the PIDs of your listeners thanks to `/tmp/listener*.pid` files.

Mind what [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html#Signals) says:

> If Bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the command completes. When Bash is waiting for an asynchronous command via the `wait` builtin, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set will cause the `wait` builtin to return immediately with an exit status greater than `128`, immediately after which the trap is executed.

This means you should run `aplay` in the background and `wait` for it (like above).

---

I can only guess you run multiple listeners to be able to serve multiple clients (still at most one client per port at any given time). Then you occasionally need to kill `aplay`, e.g. when a client silently disappears and `nc` is not notified.

Maybe this *entire* approach can be replaced by a single `socat`:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:9001,fork EXEC:'aplay -'
```

Thanks to `fork` it can serve multiple clients on the same port. Use the `-T` option (see `man 1 socat`) to terminate stale connections. Even without `-T` they should [timeout eventually](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html) anyway. The solution is vulnerable to a DOS attack though.

Comment: Many thanks. I went with your "trap 'kill "$!"' SIGUSR2" suggestion and multiple listeners, although netcat continued to give problems so I changed the netcat line in listener.sh to socat TCP-LISTEN:900$1 EXEC:'aplay -'. This seems very solid. Your last example, unless I'm mistaken, I can't use as I would need to be able to kill the individual forked aplay process and I can't see a way of doing that. Out of curiosity, in the listener.sh script, is there a way of getting the pid of nc (now socat in my script) in addition to aplay? All the best,

Comment: @sebinho [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156140/108618) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1652680/10765659), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3345460/10765659).